# How to create this wrapper

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, wrapper

I have the following script intended to be executed within a view only after a form field has been fully loaded:

```
<%= f.text_area :text, id='myfield' %>
<script>
  $('myfield').ready(function() {
    script line;
  });
</script>
```

The code isn't fully working (sometimes the script line isn't executed and sometimes it does for exactly the same page (just reloading it a couple of times)). How should I adjust the code, or is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('[name="myfield"]').on(event, function() {
    // Script
  });
});
```

Where your HTML should be like:

```
<input name="myfield" />
```

And the `event` can be any of the `click`, `keyup`, etc.

Comment: I don't think that that's what I need. The script manipulates the line `<%= f.text_area :text, id='myfield' %>` which needs to be outside the script. I can confirm that the following works: `<%= f.text_area :text, id='myfield' %>` `<script>` `script line` `</script>`. The only problem then is that sometimes it wants to execute the script before the text_area has been loaded, which I why I want to add the wrapper.

Comment: If you add stuff inside `$(document).ready(function () { });` that will execute any script after the form is loaded. Will you try it out?

Comment: Ok, will try, but not sure how to implement this. 1) what should event be? 2) I have no idea how I could include the whole `f.text_area ...` in the script.

Comment: I don't know... What were you trying to do after form load?